# WIKIDATA property and value inheritance in "instance of" relation

Tags: wikidata

If X is instance of Y can I say that the properties=value of Y are also properties of X and assign X also the properties=value of the subclasses of Y?

For example, I know that "Futbol Club Barcelona" is instance of "association football club" but I don't know which sport "Barcelona" plays while this is declared among the properties of "association football club" (sport=football). So can I associate the properties/values of "association football club" with "Futbol Club Barcelona" and say that "Futbol Club Barcelona" sport=football?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally properties are implied for an instance (P31) or subclass (P279). But there might be properties that are specific to the parent-items (like IDs or something like "has list": "list of association football clubs") that are not that usefull for a child-item. Also, although it's implied, query languages like SPARQL don't respect these inheritances.